# Change orm mapping from xml to annotations

Tags: symfony, orm

I already have all my model created with xml mapping files...is there a way to remove them and create annotations instead, with all information preserved?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i guess this should work `php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the migration manually.

[Doctrine reference](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html)

[Doctrine bundle config](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html)